# WinApi: Can the message loop be interrupted by an Async Procedure Call?

Tags: c++, winapi, asynchronous, message-queue, mouse-hook

The following code register a low level mouse hook to monitor mouse events globally.
It's the simplest working example I can get.
Compiled with VC++ 2010: `cl test.cpp /link /entry:mainCRTStartup /subsystem:windows`

```
#include <windows.h>

HWND label1 ;

//THE HOOK PROCEDURE
LRESULT CALLBACK mouseHookProc(int aCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    static int msgCount = 0 ;
    static char str[20] ;
    SetWindowText( label1, itoa(++msgCount, str, 10) ) ;
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, aCode, wParam, lParam) ;
}

int main(){
    /**///  STANDARD WINDOW CREATION PART //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /**/        
    /**/    WNDCLASSEX classStruct = { sizeof(WNDCLASSEX), 0, DefWindowProc, 0, 0, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL,
    /**/                            LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW), HBRUSH(COLOR_BTNFACE+1), NULL, "winClass", NULL } ;
    /**/    RegisterClassEx(&classStruct) ;
    /**/
    /**/    HWND mainWin = CreateWindow("winClass", "", 0, 200,200, 100,100, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) ;
    /**/    ShowWindow(mainWin, SW_SHOWDEFAULT) ;
    /**/
    /**/    label1 = CreateWindow("static", "0", WS_CHILD, 5,5, 80,20, mainWin, NULL, NULL, NULL) ;
    /**/    ShowWindow(label1, SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE) ;
    /**/
    /**///  END OF WINDOW CREATION PART ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //HOOK INSTALATION  
    HHOOK hookProc = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, mouseHookProc, GetModuleHandle(NULL), 0) ;

    //MESSAGE LOOP
    MSG msg ;
    while( GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) ){
        TranslateMessage(&msg) ;
        DispatchMessage(&msg) ;
    }

    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hookProc) ;
}
```

It's the basic one thread, one window, one message pump example. Except for the mouse hook.

My doubt is that what this code is doing contradicts two things I've read over and over in SO, MSDN, forums, blogs, etc..

1. Global hook procedures must reside in a DLL
   [MSDN documentation for `SetWindowsHookEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx) confirms this by saying:

   > If the dwThreadId parameter is zero, the lpfn parameter **MUST** point to a hook procedure in a DLL
2. A GUI thread (one with a message pump) can't be interrupted because `GetMessase`'s waiting state is not alertable. Which means that when `GetMessage` blocks in wait for more messages, it cannot receive a signal that interrupts its wait state.

However, there's no DLL anywhere to be seen here, and also the hook procedure must be interrupting the thread, otherwise the program wouldn't work, and it does (I'm assuming there's only one thread in this program).

So either I've completely misinterpreted these two points or this code is working in a way that doesn't match the asynchronous procedure call approach that I was expecting.

Either way, I'm cluless as to what is happening here.

Could you please explain how this code works.
Is it a single-thread program?
Is the hook procedure interrupting the thread?
Are any of the two points above actually true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

hook procedure must be in a DLL only if hook is need be injected into another process.
for `WH_MOUSE_LL`

> However, the WH_MOUSE_LL hook is not injected into another process.
>   Instead, the context switches back to the process that installed the
>   hook and it is called in its original context. Then the context
>   switches back to the application that generated the event.

so here not need DLL (for what ??) and hook procedure can be placed in EXE too.

> Is it a single-thread program?

in general yes. if not take to account possible system working threads, however all messages and hooks called in context of first thread

> Is the hook procedure interrupting the thread?

from MSDN

> This hook is called in the context of the thread that installed it.
>   The call is made by sending a message to the thread that installed the
>   hook. Therefore, the thread that installed the hook must have a
>   message loop.

so may say that `mouseHookProc` called inside `GetMessage` call. this function wait in kernel for messages. when system want call hook procedure, it do this via `KiUserCallbackDispatcher` call.
"interrupting the thread" - what you mean under interrupting ?

1.) this is not true, as show this example. hook procedure must be in a DLL, only if hook must be called in context of thread which received message, so in arbitrary process context - in this case we need inject code to another process - because this and DLL need. if we called always in self process context - no injection, not need DLL

2.) `GetMessage` really wait not in alertable state, so any APC cannot be delivered when code wait in `GetMessage`, but APC here absolute not related. APC and windows messaging different features. of course exist and similar points. for both APC and some windows message delivery, thread must wait in kernel . for APC in alertable state, for windows messages in `GetMessage` or `PeekMessage`. for APC delivery system call `KiUserApcDispatcher`, for windows messages `KiUserCallbackDispatcher`. both is callbacks from kernel mode, but it called under different conditions

---

interruption in exactly sense this when code execution can be interrupted at arbitrary place and interrupt routine begin executed.
in this sense interrupt not exist at all in windows user mode. APC or windows messages (hook messages is special case of windows messages) never break execution at arbitrary place, but use callback mechanism instead. exceptions is special case. thread must first call some api for enter to kernel space (for windows messaging this is `GetMessage` or `PeekMessage`, for APC - wait in alertable state functions or `ZwTestAlert`). and then kernel can use callback to user space for deliver APC or windows message. at this moment only 3 callbacks point exist from kernel to user space (this unchanged from win2000 up to win10)
`KiUserApcDispatcher` - used for APC delivery ,
`KiUserCallbackDispatcher` - used for call window procedure or hook procedure
`KiUserExceptionDispatcher` - used for exception infrastructure - this most close to interrupt by sense,

Comment: Now everything makes sense. You just forgot to link the MSDN page with all that info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644986.aspx

Comment: So I gues that `DispatchMessage` decides whether to call the WindowProcedure or the HookProcedure depending on the type of message.

Comment: @GetFree: No. The hook procedure is called, **before** the target thread's message queue even sees the input event. By the time your code calls `DispatchMessage`, the hook procedure has long returned.

Comment: Who's directing control to the HookProcedure then? Is it `GetMessage`?

Comment: @GetFree - really some windows messages, including hook messages, delivered inside GetMessage (in `KiUserCallbakDispatcher` call), but some messages not delivered direct but returned from `GetMessage` and we need that manual deliver it via `DispatchMessage`

Comment: @GetFree - `HookProcedure` is called *inside* call to `GetMessage`

Comment: @GetFree: *"Who's directing control to the HookProcedure then?"* - The input system. The same system that makes sure that your application receives other input events.

Comment: @IInspectable, this part *`Therefore, the thread that installed the hook must have a message loop`* makes me think that if there's no message loop then the HookProcedure won't be called.

Comment: @GetFree - again - hook procedure called **only inside** `GetMessage` or `PeekMessage` calls. if will be no this calls(direct or indirect) - hook procedure will be not called

Comment: @GetFree: Since a low-level mouse hook is implemented by sending messages, not running a message loop on the thread that installed the hook will cause it to fail. It is not documented, how the system responds to this bug.

Comment: It's ok @RbMm, you already made clear that `GetMessage` is the one responsible for calling the HookProcedure. But @IInspectable used the term "input system", so I wanted to make sure that he was talking about the message loop.

Comment: @GetFree - really we say the same, only using different words. win32k subsystem place input event to message queue of thread, which install LL hook. but for pop message from this queue you need call `GetMessage` or `PeekMessage` - it will be not auto delivered. under "message loop" really mean calls to this functions.

Comment: @GetFree: The message loop is not part of the input system. The message loop is part of the user-mode implementation of an application. If this is still confusing, then maybe a diagram will help. See [When something gets added to a queue, it takes time for it to come out the front of the queue](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140213-00/?p=1773).

Comment: @RbMm: No, we aren't saying the same thing. I'm explaining, what is happening, while you are explaining how you assume this were happening. We cannot both be right, and in this case I take the liberty to claim, that my description of the implementation details are correct.

Comment: @GetFree when you call `GetMessage` or `PeekMessage` - messages (if exist) pop from thread message queue and delivered to WindowProc or HookProc. some type of messages, not delivered, but simply returned.

Comment: @IInspectable - I see no contradiction in our words. we describe the different parts of the process. and I also claim that describe not "how i assume this were happening" - but absolute exactly how this were happening

Comment: @RbMm: I begin to understand @GetFree's confusion. They are under the impression, that their hook application's call to `GetMessage` couldn't be interrupted. This is, of course, wrong, and `GetMessage` does indeed call the hook procedure. In fact, both the calls to `TranslateMessage` and `DispatchMessage` aren't needed for the hook application. Previously, I though the OP were referring to the target application's `GetMessage` call.

Comment: @IInspectable - fully agree with your last message. but I write the same (+/-) only on terrible English. I not saw contradiction in our words

Comment: It's settled then. `GetMessage` calls the HookProcedure when it finds a special message in the queue. Is that it?

Comment: @GetFree - may say yes.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is explicitly documented under [LowLevelMouseProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644986.aspx):

> This hook is called in the context of the thread that installed it. The call is made by sending a message to the thread that installed the hook.

When a mouse input event is about to be placed into a thread's message queue, the system sends a message to the thread that installed the hook, waits for it to return, and then continues processing the input event.

The hook need not be in a DLL for this to work. All of this is done **before** a mouse input event is placed into the target thread's input queue, so no interruption of a message retrieval function is required. Everything is executed in sequence:

- Input event is picked up from the hardware input queue.
- A message is sent to all low-level hooks.
- If any of the hooks returned a non-zero value, drop the input event.
- Otherwise, place it into the target thread's message queue.
- The target thread can pick up the input event, using any of the message retrieval functions (`GetMessage`, `PeekMessage`, etc.).

---

A few notes on how this is implemented in the hook application:

The hook application needs to run a message loop, since the system sends messages to it, to inform it about input events that are about to be placed into the target thread's input queue by the Raw Input Thread. The `GetMessage` call (in the hook application) acts as a dispatcher in case of the hook messages, and calls into the hook procedure before returning. Even though `GetMessage` is a blocking call, it can be woken (without being alertable<sup>1)</sup>). It is probably waiting on an [Event object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682655.aspx) that gets signaled, whenever a message is available for retrieval. As an aside, both calls to `TranslateMessage` and `DispatchMessage` aren't required in your hook application.

---

<sup>1)</sup> *Reference: [The alertable wait is the non-GUI analog to pumping messages](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060503-11/?p=31323).*

Comment: To be absolutely clear, Is it the second step *`A message is sent to all low-level hooks`* where my `mouseHookProc` is called?

Comment: @GetFree: I misunderstood part of your question. I'm going to address this in an update.